# Rendering title tag based on a particular condition in sightly AEM

Tags: aem, sightly, aem-6

I am trying to render title on a page based on certain conditions.

Here is the pseudo code for what I want to achieve:
 if `currentPage.pageTitle` is set, then render title as `<title>${currentPage.pageTitle} | ${'page.title' @ i18n}</title>`
if `currentPage.pageTitle` is not set (i.e. is null), then render title as `<title>${'page.title' @ i18n}</title>`

Right now I was trying to do something like this : `<title data-sly-set.title="${currentPage.pageTitle || page.title}">${'page.title' @ i18n, format=[title]}</title>` but I want to modify it based on the conditions mentioned above.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the `|` conditionally and take advantage that a falsy expression does not render:

```
<title>${currentPage.pageTitle}${currentPage.pageTitle?' | ':''}${'page.title' @ i18n}</title>
```